# React Multi Step Forms - HMTL warnings don't work

Tags: html, reactjs, forms

I'm building a multistep form using React and following the approach from [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/the-magic-of-react-based-multi-step-forms/) and Brad Traversy's [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zT62eVxShsY) and  [code](https://github.com/bradtraversy/react_step_form)

Everything is working fine except for displaying the html warnings when a required filed isn't filled out or the user has entered a value below the minimum allowed value etc.

I could code for this using javascript but this will be very time consuming because different (required) fields render on the form depending on options selected.

Here is a summary of my code for one of the components:

```
export class EventDetails extends Component {
  continue = (e) => {
    this.props.nextStep();
  };

  render() {
    const { values } = this.props;
    return (
      <form>
        <h2>Event Details</h2>
        <div>
          <input
            required
            value={values.title}
            onChange={(event) => this.props.changeField(event, "title")}
            type="text"
            placeholder="Event Name"
          />
        </div>

        <div>
          <textarea
            value={values.description}
            required
            onChange={(event) => this.props.changeField(event, "description")}
            type="text"
            placeholder="Describe the event"
          />
        </div>

        <div>
          <select
            required
            value={values.region}
            onChange={(event) => this.props.changeField(event, "region")}
          >
            <option value="" disabled>
              Select your Region
            </option>
            <option value="dublin">Dublin</option>
            <option value="cork">Cork</option>
            <option value="other">Other</option>
          </select>
        </div>

        <div>
          <input
            required
            value={values.venue}
            onChange={(event) => this.props.changeField(event, "venue")}
            type="text"
            placeholder="Name of Venue"
          />
        </div>

        <div>
          <input
            required
            value={values.address1}
            onChange={(event) => this.props.changeField(event, "address1")}
            type="text"
            placeholder="Street Address"
          />
        </div>

        <div>
          <input
            required
            value={values.address2}
            onChange={(event) => this.props.changeField(event, "address2")}
            type="text"
            placeholder="Address Line 2"
          />
        </div>

        <div>
          <input
            value={values.address3}
            onChange={(event) => this.props.changeField(event, "address3")}
            type="text"
            placeholder="Address Line 3 (optional)"
          />
        </div>

        <div>
          <input
            value={values.address4}
            onChange={(event) => this.props.changeField(event, "address4")}
            type="text"
            placeholder="Address Line 4 (optional)"
          />
        </div>

        <div>
          <DatePicker
            timeIntervals={15}
            selected={values.startDetails}
            onChange={(event) => this.props.changeField(event, "startDetails")}
            showTimeSelect
            dateFormat="Pp"
            required
            placeholderText={"Date & Time Event Starts"}
          />
        </div>

        <div>
          <DatePicker
            timeIntervals={15}
            selected={values.endDetails}
            onChange={(event) => this.props.changeField(event, "endDetails")}
            showTimeSelect
            dateFormat="Pp"
            required
            placeholderText={"Date & Time Event Ends"}
          />
        </div>

        <div>
          <input
            value={values.eventPassword}
            required
            onChange={(event) => this.props.changeField(event, "eventPassword")}
            type="password"
            placeholder="password to check customers in"
          />
        </div>

        <button onClick={(event) => this.continue(event)}>Continue</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default EventDetails;
```

How do I make the usual HTML warnings appear and prevent the form from moving to the next step if required fields are not filled out?

Answer (score 0):

If by popup, you mean for an actual visual display in a box anywhere with a message, I believe its something you have to develop yourself or use a library like Material-UI found here https://material-ui.com/

**UPDATE:**

Below are some HTML5 attributes you could use. I hope that is what you are asking for.

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="datemax">Enter a date before 1980-01-01:</label>
  <input type="date" id="datemax" name="datemax" max="1979-12-31"><br><br>

  <label for="datemin">Enter a date after 2000-01-01:</label>
  <input type="date" id="datemin" name="datemin" min="2000-01-02"><br><br>
  
  <label for="quantity">Quantity (between 1 and 5):</label>
  <input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" min="1" max="5"><br><br>
  
  <label for="name">required field:</label>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required><br><br>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

If you want to do this in reactjs here is a quick article to use: https://codeburst.io/how-to-use-html5-form-validations-with-react-4052eda9a1d4

Its just a few things you could be missing. check out this sandbox it has an example https://codesandbox.io/s/o74l63l8v5?from-embed

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: No I'm just trying to get the regular html warning to appear

Comment: What is a regular HTML Warning? Do you mean the HTML5 checks? Those ones do not come with warnings. HTML barely warns anyone... Am confused.

Comment: yes, the regular html checks. So if an input is 'required' but user leaves it blank and clicks continue, it should display warning along the lines of 'you must fill in this field'

Comment: Alright. I have updated my answer. Check if that is what you need.